# CSS set link color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, colors

I need to customize something like this, I want link1 has color orange, link2 & link3 have color white at first, but after clicked the link is orange the rest are white,

their original color is black so I use CSS

```
.naomi ul li a:link {
  color : #fff !important;
}
.naomi ul li a:hover,  .naomi ul li a:active, {
  color : brown;
 }
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="naomi">
  <ul>
    <li ><a class="link1"></a></li>
     here
    <li ><a class="link2"></a></li>
    <li ><a class="link3"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me with the orange part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To color a link that has been clicked you use the pseudo class `:visited`

In your case, as it doesn't apply to all links, you need to set it to the targeted classes.

*Note, this custom CSS needs to be loaded **after** Wordpress's CSS. You also might have to adjust the rules [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so it matches Wordpress, or as a last resort, use `!important`*

```css
.naomi {
  background-color : gray;  /* added so we can see the white links */
}
.naomi .link1 {
  color : orange;
}
.naomi .link2,
.naomi .link3 {
  color : #fff;
}
.naomi .link2:visited,
.naomi .link3:visited {
  color : orange;
}
.naomi .link1:hover,
.naomi .link2:hover,
.naomi .link3:hover,
.naomi .link1:active,
.naomi .link2:active,
.naomi .link3:active {
  color : brown;
 }
```

```html
<div class="naomi">
  <ul>
    <li ><a class="link1" href="#1">Link1</a> more text </li>
    <li ><a class="link2" href="#2">Link2</a> more text </li>
    <li ><a class="link3" href="#3">Link3</a> more text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :visited property

```
a:visited {color:orange}
```

Comment: I don't know why I set visited it doesn't do anything  but add !important now everything become orange, I  still don't know why, I'm customing wordpress

Comment: `:visited` is a pseudo class, not a property